# MySQL query de rango

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero poder saber el valor de un producto dependiendo de las medidas que entrege el cliente, tener en cuenta que el cliente ingresa solamente una medida.

```
┌──────────┬──────┬─────┬────────┐
│ Articulo │ min  | max │ Valor  │
├──────────┼──────┼─────┼────────┤
│ EGP      │ 2.01 │ 8   │  $100  |
│ EGP      │ 8.01 │ 10  │  $200  |
│ EGP1     │ 2.01 │ 3   │  $300  |
│ EGP3     │ 8.01 │ 10  │  $400  |
└─────────────────┴─────┴────────┘
```

Aqui mi query

```
$medida = '8';
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM  tbl_Producto AS p
            WHERE p.Articulo='EGP' 
    AND p.min BETWEEN $medida AND $medida 
    AND p.max BETWEEN $medida AND $medida ";
```

Con la siguiente query deberia obtener el valor `$100`, pero no obtengo nada.
Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: ¿Por que en tu tabla la columna se llama `Articulo` pero en tu consulta `cal_producto`?

Comment: @Aprendiz Error mio

Comment: ¿Por qué no escribes tu consulta así: `SELECT * FROM  tbl_Producto AS p
            WHERE p.Articulo='EGP' 
    AND $medida BETWEEN p.min AND p.max` ? Es más simple y debería funcionar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es que debes preguntar al revés de como lo estás haciendo, `$medida` es la que debería estar en el rango `p.min` y `p.max`

```
SELECT * 
       FROM  tbl_Producto AS p
       WHERE p.Articulo='EGP' 
             AND $medida BETWEEN p.min AND p.max
```

Comment: Justo eso acabo de sugerir en comentario. Quizá convendría subrayar que `BETWEEN` es *inclusivo*. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano, sí, lo ví tarde, sino te hubiera sugerido que lo pongas como respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Ningún problema, lo importante es aportar una solución.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho thanks my budda funciono muy bien